# Finding Largest Palindromic Number which is Product of two 3 digit numbers

Tags: python, algorithm, math

Disclaimer: There are a lot of palindromic number questions based on the one on Project Euler but this one is slightly different, I promise.

Question:

> A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The smallest 6 digit
> palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers is 101101=143*707.
>
> Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit
> numbers which is less than N (a given input which contains 6 digits).

So to make an efficient algo, after doing my research on Palindromic numbers, I concluded this fact:
**All even digit palindromic numbers are divisible by 11. But all 6 digit multiples of 11 are not palindromic.**

```
def palc(n):
near=(n-(n%11))
for i in range(near,100000,-11):
    if str(i)==str(i)[::-1]:
        for j in range(990,110,-11):
            if (i%j)==0 and len(str(i//j))==3:
                return i
```

So I submitted this solution in a coding site and I passed every known test cases and all unknown test cases EXCEPT one. So the sad part is its a hidden test case and I tried to print the test case but still didn't work.

Is there a still more easier way to make it more efficient? Please kindly help me.

Comment: You concluded the fact or you know for a fact of the divisibility of 6 digit palindromes?

Comment: I'd go about this by either iterating over all possible pairs of 3-digit numbers, or by iterating over all possible palindromic numbers, then checking whether there is a pair of 3-digit numbers which has the palindromic number as a product. Both of these have acceptable ~10⁶ iterations and are very simple (and thus hard to mess up).

Comment: @JesseSealand I was initially offended by your question...but now it makes total sense. I felt that I had recognized an amazing pattern. But atleast Im proud that I found it out myself:) rather than googling

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest 202 has odd number of digits. I meant even number of digits

Comment: It is true that every palindromic number with an even number of digits is divisible by 11, but a product of 3-digit numbers can be palindromic, 5-digit long and not divisible by 11. This is the case for `369 * 271 = 99999`. This is the largest panlindrome which is a product of two 3-digit numbers and is smaller than a 6-digit number  `N` for `100000 <= N < 101101`. However, the code will not return it.

Comment: @bbi But in my code we only check till 100000 right? So...Im still not getting it... like how is that impacting my code?

Comment: @bb1 Like my forloop stops at 100000

Comment: @singleslit, a max given input which contains 6 digits is `999999`, why didn't you take it?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I didn't understand. I believe I took it.
If the input is say 1000000, the near variable which checks for nearest number divisible by 11, takes into account 999999

Comment: @singleslit. "If the input is say 1000000" (which is 7 digits) - but your task has the restriction "*N (a given input which contains **6** digits)*". Or, did it mean "input N, not less than 6 digits" ?

Comment: N may be 6 digits … but there doesn’t appear to be anything in the question that says the palindrome < N has to be 6 digits. Shouldn’t you search down to 10000 (which is 100*100)?

Comment: "all 6 digit multiples of 11 are palindromic" huh?

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Accidently worded so, "are not palindromic"

Comment: "all are not palindromic" Not true either. Some are and some are not.

Answer (score 1):

Precompute the 279 6-digit palindromic numbers that are the product of 2 3-digit numbers.

Use binary search, or since the list is so small, just parse it.

Here's the list:

```
[99999, 101101, 102201, 105501, 106601, 108801, 110011, 111111, 117711, 119911, 121121, 122221, 123321, 127721, 128821, 129921, 131131, 133331, 135531, 137731, 138831, 140041, 141141, 142241, 143341, 147741, 149941, 154451, 155551, 156651, 159951, 161161, 162261, 165561, 168861, 171171, 174471, 178871, 180081, 182281, 184481, 187781, 188881, 189981, 198891, 201102, 202202, 204402, 209902, 210012, 212212, 213312, 214412, 215512, 216612, 219912, 220022, 221122, 222222, 225522, 227722, 231132, 232232, 234432, 235532, 238832, 239932, 242242, 244442, 246642, 249942, 252252, 255552, 256652, 257752, 258852, 259952, 262262, 266662, 270072, 272272, 273372, 276672, 277772, 279972, 280082, 282282, 284482, 286682, 289982, 290092, 292292, 294492, 296692, 297792, 299992, 301103, 302203, 303303, 306603, 308803, 320023, 321123, 324423, 329923, 330033, 333333, 335533, 343343, 345543, 348843, 354453, 357753, 359953, 363363, 366663, 367763, 369963, 371173, 372273, 374473, 375573, 377773, 378873, 384483, 391193, 393393, 397793, 399993, 401104, 402204, 404404, 405504, 407704, 408804, 409904, 412214, 414414, 416614, 420024, 421124, 424424, 425524, 426624, 428824, 432234, 434434, 436634, 438834, 440044, 441144, 442244, 443344, 444444, 445544, 447744, 452254, 456654, 459954, 461164, 462264, 464464, 468864, 469964, 470074, 471174, 474474, 476674, 477774, 484484, 485584, 487784, 488884, 489984, 491194, 493394, 505505, 506605, 507705, 508805, 509905, 510015, 512215, 513315, 514415, 515515, 519915, 520025, 522225, 523325, 525525, 528825, 531135, 534435, 535535, 536635, 543345, 545545, 548845, 549945, 550055, 551155, 554455, 555555, 560065, 561165, 564465, 565565, 570075, 571175, 573375, 575575, 576675, 577775, 579975, 580085, 585585, 588885, 589985, 592295, 595595, 601106, 602206, 603306, 604406, 606606, 611116, 612216, 616616, 618816, 619916, 623326, 630036, 631136, 636636, 639936, 642246, 648846, 649946, 650056, 652256, 653356, 654456, 656656, 657756, 660066, 661166, 663366, 666666, 672276, 675576, 678876, 689986, 693396, 696696, 698896, 723327, 729927, 737737, 747747, 749947, 770077, 780087, 793397, 801108, 802208, 804408, 807708, 809908, 819918, 821128, 824428, 828828, 840048, 853358, 855558, 861168, 886688, 888888, 906609]
```

Comment: And as mentioned in a previous comment, add 99999 to this list, since it is the answer for n < 101101.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something to play with. It tries to pick options based on restrictions in the multiplicand digits. We're multiplying

```
  a1a2a3
*
  b1b2b3
```

and choosing an outer digit for the palindrome restricts the options for a3 and b3. I didn't work out automation for picking the outer target digit or a1 and b1, although we could. Here's an example where those are all set to 9, leading to the highest palindrome less than 1,000,000.

JavasScript code:

```js
var outer = 9;
var a1 = 9;
var b1 = 9;

var modHash = new Array(10);
var iterations = 0;
var highest = 0;

for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++){
  modHash[i] = {0: [0]}
  for (var j = 1; j < 10; j++){
    iterations ++;
    var r = i * j % 10;
    if (modHash[i][r])
      modHash[i][r].push(j);
    else 
      modHash[i][r] = [j];
  }
}

function multiples(x, y, carry, mod){
  for (var i in modHash[x]){
    var m = (10 + mod - i - carry) % 10;
    
    if (modHash[y][m]){
      for (var j in modHash[x][i]){
        for (var k in modHash[y][m]){
          iterations ++;
          var palindrome = num(
            a1,modHash[y][m][k],x,
            b1,modHash[x][i][j],y);
          
          var str = String(palindrome);
          
          if (str == str.split("").reverse().join("") && palindrome > highest){
            console.log(palindrome);
            highest = palindrome;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

function num(a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3){
  return (100*a1 + 10*a2 + a3)
       * (100*b1 + 10*b2 + b3);
}

var a3b3s = [];

for (let x = 1; x < 10; x++) {
  for (let y = x; y < 10; y++) {
    iterations++;
    const xy = x * y;
    if (xy % 10 == outer) {
      a3b3s.push(
        [x, y, Math.floor(xy / 10)]);
    }
  }
}

console.log("[[a3,b3,carry]]: " + JSON.stringify(a3b3s));

for (var i in a3b3s){
  for (var mod = 0; mod < 10; mod++){
    let x = a3b3s[i][0],
        y = a3b3s[i][1],
        carry = a3b3s[i][2];
    multiples(x, y, carry, mod);
  }
}

console.log("Highest: " + highest);
console.log("Iterations: " + iterations);
```